# What BJT configuration (CE, CB, CC) would be ideal if I want to maximize voltage gain while minimizing distortion for a low impedance load?

Tags: transistors, bjt

Specifically I want to be able to maximize the small signal voltage gain. Is it still reasonable to use a single BJT for this or would I need to use multiple in order to also minimize distortion? If so, what would be some things I'd have to keep in mind? Some restrictions in my case are that my load is ~20 ohms and that I'd need around a gain of around ~12 dB to ~30 dB

Comment: What source impedance? What distortion? Distortion cannot be eliminated of course, but it can be made arbitrarily low, by using arbitrary numbers of transistors.

Comment: For the source impedance I am not quite sure. The distortion I'm trying to minimize is harmonic distortion if that helps

Comment: @oralairwheat There's no voltage gain with CC. So that's out. And source impedance is important for selecting between CE and CB. So *"I'm not quite sure"* is a problem here. Finally, a load of about 20 Ohms, with voltage gain of at least 4 puts severe pressure on the question of your source impedance about which you seem to have little to say. And this affects both CB and CE, likely eliminating them both if you are looking for a single BJT stage. So you are left to consider a multiple-BJT solution. Shooting for discrete? Or are ICs in the mix?

Comment: I'm only an amateur so please bear with me but I checked the specific transistor we are using (2N3906) and it has an input impedance from 2 to 12 kOhms

Comment: `need [small signal gain ~12] to ~30 dB` how close to the transit frequency?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Instead of asking this arbitrary question, state what the real problem is that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Did you want to throw in some real specs, Vcc, Imax, Rin ,Rout, f. $?

Comment: The weak little 2N3906 has a max allowed collector current of 200mA and works poorly above 50mA. The 50mA x the 29 ohms load= 1VDC max across the 20 ohms. The little transistor has a max allowed dissipation (heating power) of 625mW so 500mW is safe, then the max voltage across the transistor with 50mA in it it is 500mW/50mA= 10V. A single CE transistor produces severe distortion when it is anywhere near cutoff so keep its output level low for low distortion.

Answer (score 1):

The CE config:

- Can have **high input impedance** in general, so it can be used as the first stage after the signal source without loading it.
- Can have **high voltage gain** so it can bring the required voltage amplification.
- Has **high output impedance** (when the voltage gain is high) so it's not able to drive a low-impedance load without any extra components (e.g. an emitter follower or an impedance transformer). *NOTE: You can make the output impedance low while having high voltage gain by using very low resistances but it won't be practical because, apart from the fact that even the quiescent currents will be unnecessarily high which means unnecessarily high losses, the signal source will be loaded heavily.*

The CC config (a.k.a. emitter follower)

- Can have **high input impedance**, so it can be used as a first stage after the signal source without loading it.
- Has **low output impedance** so it can drive low-impedance loads
- Has **no voltage amplification**.

The CB config (the tricky one)

- Can have **high voltage amplification** but the **current gain is unity**. Some articles describe this as anti-emitter follower for these two properties.
- Has **low input impedance** so it's not suitable as a first stage after the signal source.
- Has **high output impedance** because the output is taken from collector. So it's not able to drive low-impedance loads.

As you can see, a single configuration is not enough for everything. To bring everything together, op amps have been invented. They are basically a combination of different configurations to bring high input impedance, high voltage gain as well as low output impedance.

Comment: Can you try to show how to get 30 dB with low out impedance?

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 as I stated in my answer, it will be impractical because you'll end up with very low collector and biasing resistances.

Comment: I got 30 dB somehow.

Answer (score 0):

> What BJT configuration (CE, CB, CC) would be ideal if I want to maximize voltage gain while minimizing distortion for a low-impedance load?

Ideal linear amplification in a single stage is always dependent on the Vbe swing which modulates current with an **exponential response**.  Thus a single device with a limited GBW will have a limited power gain that is a combination of impedance and voltage gains.

For RF, the best case solution uses CB which results in very low Zin but high Av. The series input R will determine the input impedance and may be chosen as 50 ohms.

Negative Feedback CE configuration generally permits a reduction of open loop gain which can be as high as 60 dB with a loss in conductance gain of [S=1/ohms]. With high GBW and high hFE, one can choose a component to achieve a 30 dB gain with the same Zin and out.  Negative feedback corrects THD by the amount of open loop gain reduction and hFE loss of 90% during saturation and thus maintains a more constant Vbe and reduced Zin from the open loop Rc and Rb.

I usually choose CE NFB Re = 0 to rBE and chose an Rcb/Rb = 60 to achieve a closed loop gain of 30 = 30 dB and chose an open loop gain with sufficient current to increase Id with additional base bias up or down from Vcc to 0V to choose Vce = Vcc/2 and except all the THD that cause asymmetric positive peaks vs negative when AC coupled to be reduced by the excess gain feedback.  This results in extended large signal power swings, low Z out and high gain with low THD.

The reduction in Rcb/Rin ratio to gain is due to losses in Vce variation from addition base bias attenuation.

Would you like to see a design example simulated with tolerances or try it yourself? This is beyond the scope of your specifications.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Ship it.